# problems with calling specific Api

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-chrome, http

i am pretty new to Api and the process of calling them. Right now i am trying to call a simple api but it seems i have run into a problem. i don't know weather the problem is the network class i created or how i fetched the data. i need help.

This is the network class

```
class Network {
  Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
    var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    Response response = await(get(Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull(api))));

      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Data> listOf = [];

    for (var i in jsonData) {
      Data data = Data(i['id'], i['title'], i['url'], i['thumbnail']);
      listOf.add(data);
    }
    return listOf;
  }
}
```

This is the model i created for the api

```
class Data{
  int id;
  String title;
  String url;
  String thumbnail;

  Data(this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnail);
}
```

This is the main code

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late Future<List<Data>> data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    data = Network().getData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 250,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: data,
                builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData) {
                 
                  return Text(snapshot.data[2]['title']);
                }else{
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                }
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: can you share error you facing

Answer (score 0):

Almost there by the looks of it! Two things that need attention:

1. Parsing of JSON response data fails because the endpoint returns a different data structure: `i['thumbnail']` needs to be `i['thumbnailUrl']`.
2. The reference to the `title` inside the `Text` widget needs to be: `Text(snapshot.data[2].title)`

That should do the trick and show you some visuals.